# Summarize a column by several inputs using AWK

Tags: c++, sql, awk, bigdata

I have big data with billion of rows on unix txt file. I need to provide a specification for my C++ developers and a summary example.

I need to summarize the following format:

[raw data table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEQHt.png)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10    Column11    Column12    Column13    Column14    Column15    Column16    Column17    Column18
Ax1,Ay1 Bx1,By1 C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 K1  L1  M1  N1  O1  P1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1
Ax2,Ay2 Bx2,By2 C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 K1  L1  M1  N1  O1  P1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1
Ax2,Ay3 Bx2,By3 C3  D3  E3  F3  G3  H1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 K3  L3  M3  N3  O3  P3  Qx3,Qy3 Rx3,Ry3
Ax4,Ay4 Bx4,By4 C4  D4  E4  F4  G4  H4  Ix4,Iy4 Jx1,Jy4 K4  L4  M4  N4  O4  P4  Qx4,Qy4 Rx4,Ry4
Ax5,Ay5 Bx5,By5 C5  D5  E5  F5  G5  H5  Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5 K5  L5  M5  N5  O5  H5  Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5
Ax6,Ay6 Bx6,By6 C2  D2  E3  F3  G3  H3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3 K2  L2  M3  N3  O3  P3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3
Ax7,Ay7 Bx7,By7 C7  D7  E3  F3  G3  H3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3 K7  L7  M3  N3  O3  P3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3
Ax8,Ay8 Bx8,By8 C8  D8  E8  F8  G8  H3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3 K8  L8  M8  N8  O8  P3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3
Ax9,Ay9 Bx9,By9 C9  D9  E9  F9  G9  H9  Ix9,Iy9 Jx1,Jy9 K9  L9  M9  N9  O9  P9  Qx9,Qy9 Rx9,Ry9
Ax10,Ay10   Bx10,By10   C10 D10 E10 F10 G10 H10 Ix10,Iy10   Jx1,Jy10    K10 L10 M10 N10 O10 P10 Qx10,Qy10   Rx10,Ry10
```

I would like to summarize the number of counts of column 8 by 9, 10, 16,17 and 18.

And obtain format this.

[result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMLLn.png)

```
Count   Column8 Column9 Column10    Column16    Column17    Column18
2   H1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 P1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1
1   H1  Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 P3  Qx3,Qy3 Rx3,Ry3
1   H4  Ix4,Iy4 Jx1,Jy4 P4  Qx4,Qy4 Rx4,Ry4
1   H5  Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5 H5  Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5
3   H3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3 P3  Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3
1   H9  Ix9,Iy9 Jx1,Jy9 P9  Qx9,Qy9 Rx9,Ry9
1   H10 Ix10,Iy10   Jx1,Jy10    P10 Qx10,Qy10   Rx10,Ry10
```

People told me the right way to do this is by using AWK. Any suggestion? Any faster alternative?
 I have been google'ing this but, i do not find this so straight forward on AWK. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: If possible please provide sample text data set rather than a picture of it

Comment: I did add that...but, i do not think there is easy to see that way. This is why i thought picture was better

Comment: Actually that way we could verify our results

Comment: thanks, good thing is that somebody suggested some new view that helps with the visualization. Thanks, folks

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR!=1{uniqueSet[$8" "$9" "$10" "$16" "$17" "$18]++}END{print "Count   Column8 Column9 Column10    Column16    Column17    Column18"; for(i in uniqueSet) print uniqueSet[i]" "i}' <file_name>
```

First the awk will iterate over each row and count the iterations of the rows based on your "key" and in the end it will print the count with the "key"

Output

```
Count   Column8 Column9 Column10    Column16    Column17    Column18
1 H4 Ix4,Iy4 Jx1,Jy4 P4 Qx4,Qy4 Rx4,Ry4
3 H3 Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3 P3 Ix3,Iy3 Jx1,Jy3
1 H10 Ix10,Iy10 Jx1,Jy10 P10 Qx10,Qy10 Rx10,Ry10
1 H1 Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 P3 Qx3,Qy3 Rx3,Ry3
2 H1 Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1 P1 Ix1,Iy1 Jx1,Jy1
1 H9 Ix9,Iy9 Jx1,Jy9 P9 Qx9,Qy9 Rx9,Ry9
1 H5 Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5 H5 Ix5,Iy5 Jx1,Jy5
```

Comment: This does not work. I got the total number of rows. 8592855 and not what i intended. This is a step forward but, not what is needed. i will look if i can modify this